# editing ajax form commands

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xhtml

How can I change the below code of the submit button, to a code that will also print and/or return to top of page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com
/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/
recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C|/Users/CRAIG
/Desktop/test/form_files/ajax-form.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C|/Users/CRAIG/Desktop
/test/form_files/jquery.ajax-form.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#JQAjaxForm1').fdAjaxForm({formEmailURL:"file:///C|/Users/CRAIG
/Desktop/test/form_files/email.php",formFileUploadURL:"file:///C|/Users
/CRAIG/Desktop/test/form_files/file_upload.php"});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="JQAjaxForm1" class="JQAjaxForm" action="?" method="post">
  <div class="cf_form_content">
    <div class="cf_form_element cf_basic_element cf_required">
      <div class="cf_field_cover"> <span> <span class="cf_main_label">
  <span>Name:</span></span> <span class="cf_sub_label"><span>your
 name</span></span> </span>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Your name" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cf_form_element cf_email_element cf_required">
  <div class="cf_field_cover"> <span> <span class="cf_main_label">
<span>Email:</span></span> <span class="cf_sub_label"><span>a valid
 email</span></span> </span>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="email[]" placeholder="Your name" data-val-
type="email" />
      <i class="cf_icon_mail"></i> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cf_form_element cf_textarea_element cf_required">
  <div class="cf_field_cover"> <span> <span class="cf_main_label">
<span>Message:</span></span> <span class="cf_sub_label"><span>more
 details</span></span> </span>
    <div>
      <textarea name="message[]" rows="5" placeholder="Type your message
here..."></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cf_form_element cf_submit_element">
  <div class="cf_field_cover">
    <div>
      <div class="cf_submit" style="text-align:right">
        <div class="cf_submit_button" style="float:right"> <span
 class="cf_label">Submit</span> <span class="cf_icon_submit"></span>
</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the whole ui for the submission form. The latter section has the coding to submit the form. I am not sure what else to add/contribute to help.

Comment: By coding of course. Or if you are a Hogwarts Alumni, give that magic wand of yours a wave.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to be a little more specific with your problem but here's my answer:

```
<div class="cf_form_element cf_submit_element">
  <div class="cf_field_cover">
    <div>
      <div class="cf_submit" style="text-align:right">
        <button class="cf_submit_button" style="float:right">
            <!--I'm guessing that's your submit button-->
            <span class="cf_label">Submit</span>
            <span class="cf_icon_submit"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="cf_submit_button" style="float:right" onclick="f()">
            <span class="cf_label">Print</span><!--Print button-->
            <span class="cf_icon_print"></span>
        </button>

    <script>
    function f(){
        window.print();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I want to insert a print button next to the submit button, and have the same css style of the submit button, for the print button.

Comment: @NumNum Sooo... which one exactly _is_ your submit button?

Comment: The top one, the secondary one would be a print button (or vise versa as I guess it doesn't really matter). This coding is within an ajax form, of which i know nothing about. The idea is someone could fill out a form online, and print it just before they submit it.

Comment: Could you add the AJAX to your answer? It would help a lot.

Comment: I added the entire ui to the original coding.